# How to handle nested objects in processing a JSON stream

Tags: php, json, stream

I am working on a program where we need to process very large JSON file, so I would like to use a streaming event oriented reader (like [jsonstreamingparser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser)) so that we can avoid loading the entire structure into memory at one time. Something I'm concerned about though is the object structure that seems to be required to make this work. 
For example, say I'm writing a program like Evite to send out invitations to an activity, with a JSON structure like:

```
{  
  "title": "U2 Concert",  
  "location": "San Jose",  
  "attendees": [  
    {"email": "foo@bar.com"},  
    {"email": "baz@bar.com"}
  ],  
  "date": "July 4, 2015"  
}
```

What I would like to do is have a programming "event" that when the stream encounters a new attendee, sends out an invite email.  **But**, I can't do that because the stream has not yet reached the date of the event.
Of course, given the example, it's fine to just read everything into memory - but my dataset has complex objects where the "attendees" attribute are, and there can be tens of thousands of them.

Another "solution" is to just mandate: you HAVE to put all the required "parent" attributes first, but that is what I'm trying to find a way around.

Any ideas?

Comment: A solution would to read the stream twice. The first time you read all mandatory attributes. The second time you process the attendees and send out invitations (that's not elegant but you'll have only streams and you control the memory limit)

Comment: Well, I do have some control over the JSON structure.  My worry is that clients who generate the JSON might not have as much control over things like the ordering of object attributes...so when they tell their code to convert an object to JSON, the object attribute order might not be controllable.

Comment: iam_decoder - thanks for the edits!

Comment: @Ryan Vincent, I have been working with jsonstreamingparser, and it is the thing that I'm concerned about - it will publish that a child object has been found before all the attributes of the parent have been recorded. I suppose that's the nature of streaming. But I'm looking for a clever way to mitigate that risk. Thanks

Comment: One comment about jsonstreamingparser, I got it to work fine, but I wasn't happy with the performance. I have a pretty big file that json_decode took .2 seconds, but jsonstreamingparser took 21 seconds :(   It did use half the memory though.

Comment: Right, i now understand the problem - If i could just learn to read ;-/ It has to be two logical passes. I would process the attendees on the first pass but store them, serialized, in a file. The second pass processes the 'serialized attendees' file. If you require any assistance to modify the code post a comment.It won't take long.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent - Two passes would work, but not in practice.  Right now it takes jsonstreamingparser 20 seconds to process my json one time...so doubling that just won't fly.  I think what I may end up having to do is to go "relational" and split up the two passess into separate json objects, or even files.  So instead of attendees being a child object of event, they would be a contained in a sibling object.  So level 1 would have a list of event objects with ids, then the next level 1 object would be an array of attendee sets which have an id and a child list of attendees. That would be "safe"

Comment: As speed is a concern, have you considered using a language other than PHP to do the parsing? There are JSON stream Parser available for most of the 'compiled' languages. This assumes that the system is not 'IO bound'. A 'solid state drive' may be useful? :)

Comment: It is my belief that the original problem I posed would be the same in any language's streaming parser.  So I first wanted to explore the possibility of making the parser less dependent on a concrete ordering in the JSON itself.  

That being said, yes, there are other ways to speed things up.  But I don't think the issue is necessarily with external things, like hard drive speed, or even language choice, because php's own json_decode takes .2 seconds vs 20 seconds for streaming.  But let's not get into the weeds trying to optimize my situation in this question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is another 'tree walking' problem. The [JSON streaming parser](http://blog.salsify.com/engineering/json-streaming-parser-for-php) reads the source file and starts to build the 'tree'. It does this by collecting 'elements' and storing them in memory. To enable us to process each entry, it 'emits events' at convenient times. Which means it will call your functions passing useful values as required.

Examples of 'tree events' are:

- start_object()
- end_object()
- start_array()
- end_array()
- ...

  The 'example' code provided with the 'Parser' is a program that uses the Parser to build the tree in memory. I just modified that example to call our function whenever it has a 'complete Event' stored.

So, how do we identify a 'complete Event'?

The input file consist of an array where each entry is a JSON 'obbject'. Each object consists of 'sub entries' that make up the data of the 'object'.

Now, as we traverse the 'tree' building it, our code will be called at various points as shown above. Specifically when 'starting' and 'ending' of objects and arrays. We need to collect all the data for the 'outer object'.

How do we identify this? We record where we are in the 'tree' as the processing proceeds. This we do by keeping track of the depth of 'nesting' in the tree. Hence the 'levels'. The 'start' of an object 'nests' down one level, the 'end' of an object 'unnests' one level.

The objects we are interested in are a 'level 1'.

The code provided:
   1) keeps track of the 'levels' and calls our function when it reaches the end of an object that is at 'level 1'.
   2) Accumulates the data in the appropriate structure from the start of the the object at 'level 1'.

Requirements:

1) Call a 'callable' routine when there is a 'complete Event' that can be processed.

Assumptions:

- The input file consists of an array of 'Events'.

Processing:

- Parse the file
- Whenever the current Event is 'complete'
- Execute the 'processEvent' callable with access to the current Event.

Source Code:

- [Source: class Q31079129Listener at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/MNkmd4kR)
- [Source: index.php file at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/pYr2Geum)
- [Source: test datafile : Q31079129.json at Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/bVkVCJ2n)
- [Demonstration using the code](http://rfv123.eu.pn/jsonevents/)

Code: index.php

```
<?php // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079129/how-to-handle-nested-objects-in-processing-a-json-stream

require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/jsonstreamingparser/src/JsonStreamingParser/Parser.php';
require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/jsonstreamingparser/src/JsonStreamingParser/Listener/IdleListener.php';

require_once __DIR__ .'/Q31079129Listener.php';

/**
 * The input file consists of a JSON array of 'Events'.
 *
 * The important point is that when the file is being 'parsed' the 'listener' is
 * 'walking' the tree.
 *
 * Therefore
 *  1) Each 'Event' is at 'level 1' in the tree.
 *
 *  Event Level Changes:
 *   Start: level will go from 1 => 2
 *   End:   level will go from 2 => 1  !!!!
 *
 *  Actions:
 *      The 'processEvent' function will be called when the
 *      'Event Level' changes to 2 from 1.
 *
 */
define('JSON_FILE', __DIR__. '/Q31079129.json');

/**
 * This is called when one 'Event' is complete
 *
 * @param type $listener
 */
function processEvent($listener) {
    echo '<pre>', '+++++++++++++++';
    print_r($listener->get_event());
    echo '</pre>';
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// the 'Listener'
$listener = new Q31079129Listener();

// setup the 'Event' Listener that will be called with each complete 'Event'
$listener->whenLevelAction = 'processEvent';

// process the input stream
$stream = fopen(JSON_FILE, 'r');
try {
  $parser = new JsonStreamingParser_Parser($stream, $listener);
  $parser->parse();
}
    catch (Exception $e) {
        fclose($stream);
        throw $e;
}
fclose($stream);
exit;
```

Code: Q31079129Listener.php

```
<?php // // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079129/how-to-handle-nested-objects-in-processing-a-json-stream

/**
 * This is the supplied example modified:
 *
 * 1) Record the current 'depth' of 'nesting' in the current object being parsed.
 */
class Q31079129Listener extends JsonStreamingParser\Listener\IdleListener {

    public $whenLevelAction = null;

    protected $event;
    protected $prevLevel;
    protected $level;


    private $_stack;
    private $_keys;

    public function get_event() {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function get_prevLevel() {
        return $this->prevLevel;
    }

    public function get_level() {
        return $this->prevLevel;
    }

    public function start_document() {
        $this->prevLevel = 0;
        $this->level = 0;


        $this->_stack = array();
        $this->_keys = array();
        // echo '<br />start of document';
    }

    public function end_document() {
       //  echo '<br />end of document';
    }

    public function start_object() {
        $this->prevLevel = $this->level;
        $this->level++;
        $this->_start_complex_value('object');
    }

    public function end_object() {
        $this->prevLevel = $this->level;
        $this->level--;
        $this->_end_complex_value();
    }

    public function start_array() {
        $this->prevLevel = $this->level;
        $this->level++;
        $this->_start_complex_value('array');
    }

    public function end_array() {
        $this->prevLevel = $this->level;
        $this->level--;
        $this->_end_complex_value();
    }

    public function key($key) {
        $this->_keys[] = $key;
    }

    public function value($value) {
        $this->_insert_value($value);
    }

    private function _start_complex_value($type) {
        // We keep a stack of complex values (i.e. arrays and objects) as we build them,
        // tagged with the type that they are so we know how to add new values.
        $current_item = array('type' => $type, 'value' => array());
        $this->_stack[] = $current_item;
    }


    private function _end_complex_value() {
        $obj = array_pop($this->_stack);

    // If the value stack is now at level 1 from level 2,
    // we're done parsing the current complete event, so we can
    // move the result into place so that get_event() can return it. Otherwise, we
    // associate the value

//    var_dump(__FILE__.__LINE__, $this->prevLevel, $this->level, $obj);

    if ($this->prevLevel == 2  && $this->level == 1) {
        if (!is_null($this->whenLevelAction)) {
            $this->event = $obj['value'];
            call_user_func($this->whenLevelAction, $this);
            $this->event = null;
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->_insert_value($obj['value']);
    }
  }

  // Inserts the given value into the top value on the stack in the appropriate way,
  // based on whether that value is an array or an object.
  private function _insert_value($value) {
    // Grab the top item from the stack that we're currently parsing.
    $current_item = array_pop($this->_stack);

    // Examine the current item, and then:
    //   - if it's an object, associate the newly-parsed value with the most recent key
    //   - if it's an array, push the newly-parsed value to the array
    if ($current_item['type'] === 'object') {
      $current_item['value'][array_pop($this->_keys)] = $value;
    } else {
      $current_item['value'][] = $value;
    }

    // Replace the current item on the stack.
    $this->_stack[] = $current_item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Big smile...I arrived at a similar strategy:  
    private function getLast($arr) {  
        $last = end($arr);  
        reset($arr);  
        return $last;  
    }  
    private function out($str) {echo $str . "\n";}  
    private function getAddress() {return implode('|', $this->_keys);}  
    public function end_object() {  
        if ($this->getAddress() == 'devices|events') {  
            $event = $this->getLast($this->_stack);  
            $this->out('an event:' . $event['value']['orderTimestamp']);  
        }  
        $this->_end_complex_value();  
    }

Comment: Oy, I guess putting code in comments doesn't work well :(

Comment: I appreciate your digging into the problem, but I think you're missing the core question I'm asking:  Is there anything to do to protect against processing children before all attributes of the parent are knows.  Specifically, if the processing the events in my example if they are dependent on the parent's "date" attribute which is declared after the events.

Comment: @MikeHedman, My bad, i returned an array containing the 'object type' and the 'value'. Updated the 'listener' code. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I'm not expressing my need clearly.  In your processEvent function, I need to be able to access not just the event's properties (As you've demonstrated with print_r, but I also need to print out the parent's date property.  Getting to the parent is easy, by traversing down the listener's $_stack array, but when processing the events, the parent's date property has not yet been read by the listener (it's downstream from where the reading pointer is in the json file).  So rather than print_r'ing, I want to send a mail to that address with the date...and that's the problem.

Comment: the sample data set I put in my question is the right structure...except in my real data I have 15000 objects in the "attendees" spot. This is why I'm bumping up against memory issues in my real world problem.  So it's not an option for me to first read in all those objects into memory, get the date from the parent, and then do my processing. Instead, in need to do the processing along the way and dump the "attendee" objects out of memory after they have been processed.  Thanks